# Make dynamic request using Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I want to make a dynamic request using Gatling.
using Gatling we are getting to rest-API to which we are posting an SMS request I want that each request should be done with a different sent of mob no.

```
    exec(http("Sms Delivery")
      .post(s"/deliveries")
      .body(StringBody(
        s"""{ "template":
           |{ "type":"inline", "inline":
           |  { "channels":
           |    "sms":{ "body":{ "layout":"{greeting}", "fragments":{ "greeting":{"en-US":"ABC123 Interested to hear about some jobs?"}}}} }} },
           | "recipients":[ { "contactDetails":{ "mobileNumber" : "+1${Random.nextInt(123123123)}" } }],
           |  "requester": "${UUID.random.toString}"}""".stripMargin)).asJson
      .check(status.is(202))
      .check(jsonPath("$.messageId").ofType[String])
    )
  }

setUp(
    scenario("Create message-Cmd")
      .exec(createMessageServiceSms()).inject(
      rampConcurrentUsers(0) to (6) during(1),
      constantConcurrentUsers(5) during (testTime seconds)
    )
  )
```

Let suppose Gatling sends 100 requests the for all those requests my mob no remains the same for each request is same let say `+12011705515`.
However, I want all no. should be different.

Answer (score 1):

The string is created only once, then parsed as [Expression Language](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/), which allows you to substitute in [session attributes](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/).

If you want custom functions like creating a `UUID` and calling `Random.nextInt`, you need to pass in a function to `StringBody`.

```scala
StringBody(_ =>
  s"""{ "template":
     |{ "type":"inline", "inline":
     |  { "channels":
     |    "sms":{ "body":{ "layout":"{greeting}", "fragments":{ "greeting":{"en-US":"ABC123 Interested to hear about some jobs?"}}}} }} },
     | "recipients":[ { "contactDetails":{ "mobileNumber" : "+1${Random.nextInt(123123123)}" } }],
     |  "requester": "${UUID.random.toString}"}""".stripMargin)
)
```

The parameter that we discarded is the virtual user's `Session`.

---

Worth noting that you may have too few digits for the `mobileNumber`, but that's another issue than creating a dynamic request.